# Playing a video retaining its size?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to play videos in Unity retaining its actual size?
I have a video with `Width = 2048 and Height = 2634`. I am adding the videoplayer to a Quad mesh renderer and playing the video on it. The video looks squashed. So how do I scale the mesh renderer with the video's aspect ratio?

Comment: Did you try to adjust the [`VideoPlayer.aspectRatio`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-aspectRatio.html)? Or in other words: How would you want the quad to get scaled? E.g. Keep its current width? Keep its current height?

Comment: The simpler way was to create a render texture with the aspect ratio of the video. I went along with this.